# Replace a Null value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace, null

I'm having trouble with a replace method in JavaScript. The application crashes when a value is null. What is the best way around this issue?

```
datafield.putValue(value.replace("~","&"));
```

**update**

all that was need was a simple if statement wrapped around.

```
if(value != null)
{
    datafield.putValue(value.replace("~","&"));
}
```

Comment: use ternary operator

Comment: Are you sure that's Java? Doesn't look like Java. `Replace` is capitalized and it has a JavaScript-style literal regular expression. The former suggests it's C#; the latter suggests it's JavaScript.

Comment: Let's assume it is Java: *"or is replace clever enough to not check when null"* How should a method be clever enough for that, if it isn't even called?

Comment: This is still not valid Java ...

Comment: Still has the JavaScript-style regular expression.

Comment: Apologise, have had to migrate such a big project with language that isn't my first language.

Comment: @Tom It's within a loop, probably wrong of me to assume but i didn't think it would perform a replace if the value is null.

Comment: This is not compilable in java.
Valid java expression would be: `value.replace("/~/g","&")`

Comment: is the question more appropriate now?

Comment: @tak3shi: No, that would try to replace the literal string `/~/g` with `&`. Sam, I've fixed the question with valid Java code to do a replace of `~` with `&`, globally in the string. You could also use `.replace('~', '&'`)` (the `char`-based one instead of the `CharSequence`-based one) since both the search text and the replacement are exactly one character long.

Comment: Side note: In Java, the *overwhelming* convention is that local variables and both instance and static fields start with a lowercase letter, so `value` rather than `Value`. I mention this just because you've indicated that you're having to do work in Java when it isn't a language you're very familiar with; `Value` will look like a class name to the vast majority of Java programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `if`, certainly, either to not put anything or to put `null`:

```
if (Value != null) {
    datafield.putValue(Value.replace("~","&"));
}
```

or

```
if (Value != null) {
    datafield.putValue(Value.replace("~","&"));
} else {
    datafield.putValue(null);
}
```

...but if you want to do that last one I'd use the conditional operator:

```
datafield.putValue(Value == null ? null : Value.replace("~","&"));
```

> ...or is replace clever enough to not check when null...

if `Value` is `null`, `replace` will never get called (in Java). So it's impossible for `replace` to be "clever" enough to handle it.

---

Side note: Since both the search text and the replacement are exactly one character long, you could use the [`char`-based version of `replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) instead of the [`CharSequence`-based one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-): `Value.replace('~', '&')`

Comment: @TJ Crowder Thanks for the reply, sorry for the communication issues. I was wanting to make sure that im approaching it the correct way. This worked perfectly.